# Calculating Hilbert Norm Residue Symbol

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

The following properties of the Hilbert Norm Residue Symbol are given:

1. $(a,b) = (b,a)$
2. $(a_1a_2,b)=(a_1,b)(a_2,b)$ (same for $(a,b_1b_2)$)
3. $(a,-a)=1$ for all a

We now have to reformulate i) $(a_1/b,a_2/b)$ using given properties. Our solution suggests that $(b,a_2)(b,a_1)(b,b)(a_1,a_2)=(a_1/b,a_2/b)$ but I don't understand why. In particular, I don't understand how one applies the properties on inverse numbers. Moreover, it is stated that ii) $(b,b)=(b,-1)$ and that iii) $(b,a_2)(b,a_1)(b,b)=(b,-a_1a_2)$. I get that $(b,a_2)(b,a_1)(b,b)(a_1,a_2) = (b,a_1a_2)(b,b)(a_1,a_2)$ and that $(b,a_2)(b,a_1)(b,b)=(b,a_1a_2)(b,b)$, but I don't understand how to deduce i), ii) and iii). Could someone explain the missing steps?

Comment: ii follows from 3 by writing $b =-1\cdot(-b)$. iii follows from what you have, ii, and 2.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! Any idea on how to deduce i)?

Comment: Are you sure the first two terms are not inverted in that i)? Because I get $(a_1/b, a_2/b) =\dfrac{(a_1, a_2/b)}{(b, a_2/b)} = \dfrac{(a_1, a_2)/(a_1,b)}{(b, a_2)/(b,b)}=\dfrac{(a_1, a_2)(b,b)}{(a_1,b)(a_2,b)}$.

Comment: I have asked our professor. I will let you know about his reply. Thanks a lot for your help, very appreciated!

Comment: It follows from the fact that the norm residue symbol is invariant under multiplication of elements in ${{\mathbb{Q}_p}^{\ast}}^2$. If one assumes that $b \in {{\mathbb{Q}_p}^{\ast}}$, then $(a_1,b^{-1})=(a_1,b)$ and so one.

Comment: I put page 43 of Cassels at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4412352/is-the-hilbert-symbol-non-degenerate-over-mathbbq/4412678#4412678